# ASP.NET Load different content from same file depending on url parameter

Tags: asp.net

What I'm trying to do is put the content of several ContentPages (they don't have any scripts, just different content, same layout) into a single file, separate each content into groups, and then choose what to load (using url parameters) from a single ContentPage.

It's something like a MasterPage but instead of loading all of it I'd like to choose what sections or content groups to load.

Comment: That is what User Controls are for.  You would check the url in the User Control and choose to display it or not, you can use `<asp:PlaceHolder ID="whatever" Visible="false" runat="server">`Your HTML in Here.`</asp:PlaceHolder>` and show it or not depending on the url.

Comment: You should also use:  `ContentPlaceHolder` => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.contentplaceholder(v=vs.110).aspx